# How do I hide reviews on Play Store made by my phone contacts?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, google, google-plus, google-contacts

Consider a random app on Play Store. When I visit its page, the reviews shown to me at the top of the list are mostly by my phone contacts (not Google+ contacts).

I do not follow anyone on Google+, although some people might follow me.
I have hundreds of phone numbers in my phone's contacts app which syncs with Google.

I do not wish to see reviews about an app posted by my phone contacts unless they're actually worth seeing there, I want to see reviews based on their usefulness or upvotes and I want to see reviews from total strangers mostly.

**How can I achieve this?**

OnePlus One, Cyanogen OS 13.1 non-rooted, stock, up to date so far.
Apps including Store, Services, Google+ and everything up to date so far.

Answer (score 2):

Go to People section in Google Play Store:

[image]

And unfollow everyone there.

If that doesn't help, go to Settings->Applications. Remove access to Contacts for Google Play Store, clean its Data and Cache, and reboot your device.

If that doesn't help, do the same for Google Play Services.

If that doesn't help, I doubt there is much you can do left. Google Play is not a very customizable application, unfortunately.